# Issue with shiro and ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache, shiro

I am using shiro for authentication along with ehcache.xml for enabling SSO.

My ehcache.xml looks like

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" name="my-cache">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/mycache" />


    <cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
           eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

    </cache>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true"
                  overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

I have a factory class like below

```
public class SharedEhCacheManagerFactory implements Factory<CacheManager> {

    private String cacheManagerConfigFile = "/ehcache.xml";

    @Override
    public CacheManager getInstance()
    {
        return CacheManager.create(readCacheManagerConfigFileAsInputStream());
    }

    public InputStream readCacheManagerConfigFileAsInputStream()
    {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(cacheManagerConfigFile);
        return is;
    }
}
```

And my shiro.ini files main section for all webapps is like

```
[main]
ehCacheManager = com.nokia.anv.app.security.service.SharedEhCacheManagerFactory
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
cacheManager.cacheManager=$ehCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO

cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = SSOCookie
cookie.path = /
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

I am using apache karaf and this apps comes in a docker container. When I start the container for the first time everything is fine, but if I stop and start the container I am getting the error for most of the appllications like

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The CacheManager has been shut down. It can no longer be used.
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AuthenticatingFilter.cleanup(AuthenticatingFilter.java:155)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
```

But always two applications are fine. Please let me to what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing something is calling the `destroy()` method in your CacheManager.  You could add some logging or set a break point to figure how the culprit.